# Need to use the "Google-cloud-ndb" library in Python 2.7 version

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

We are currently using the Python 2.7 and Google App Engine NDB client.
Planning to migration from Google App Engine to Google Cloud NDB

As per docs, "google-cloud-ndb" library officially supports for Python 2.7 and Python 3.x as well.
So, we are trying to access the datastore through google-cloud-ndb.

We are facing the below trace which is related to DisturbutionNotFound Error

`raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) DistributionNotFound:  The 'google-cloud-ndb' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Answer (score 0):

In Google App Engine, Python 2.7 doesn't support the use of `requirements.txt` file. This means you have to install all the modules/libraries you need for your App and deploy it together with your App to production. In your specific case, it means you have to install `google-cloud-ndb`library.

Follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) to install the libraries you need to run your App

Comment: Still facing the same issue eventhough google-cloud-ndb library is installed while deploying the service.

Comment: Are you saying you followed the instructions in the above link and you're still having problems?

Comment: Yes... already we have followed the same steps to installed the third-party libraries in our application

Comment: Inside the '/lib' folder, we can able to see the 'google-cloud-ndb' package.